# simple question about circle

Tags: geometry

Let $C$ be a circle and
$$
{\bf X_1,X_2,X_3,...}
$$

are some nodes inside the circle.

How could I find they are on which quarter of the circle?

When they are on boundary I could use $\arctan(y/x)$where ${\bf X}=(x,y)$.

But for interior nodes how to do this?

Comment: Do you know the center of the circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the circle is cenered at the origin of the coordinate system, the quadrant $(x,y)$ is in is determined by the signs of $x$ and $y$. If the center is $(u,v)$ instead, consider the signs of $x-u$ and $y-v$ instead.

Comment: Yeah, if the only information you need is the quadrant, signs will do the job